# AsyncTask doesn't always call but when it does, it comes up null?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I've looked at so many questions and answers but none of what i found has actually worked!

So basically if the title doesn't help much then what I'm trying to do is execute an AsyncTask from a dialog but it's not executing and when it does, it'll show up as an null object and if I'm honest it's bloody annoying!

So if anyone can help then that would be great.

The Class is subbed.

Here's the Async class:

```
static class UpdatePassword extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context context;
    String oldPassword;
    String newPassword;

    public UpdatePassword(String setOldPassword, String setNewPassword, Context context) {
        this.oldPassword = setOldPassword;
        this.newPassword = setNewPassword;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpRequestUtils httpRequestUtils = new HttpRequestUtils(context);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(oldPassword) || TextUtils.isEmpty(newPassword)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String response = null;
            String baseUrl = "rest/ws/user/update/password";
            ApiResponse apiResponse = null;
            try {
                response = httpRequestUtils.getResponse(baseUrl + "?oldPassword=" + oldPassword + "&newPassword=" + newPassword, "application/json", "application/json");
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(response)) {
                    return null;
                }
                apiResponse = (ApiResponse) GsonUtils.getObjectFromJson(response, ApiResponse.class);
                if (apiResponse != null && apiResponse.isSuccess()) {
                    return apiResponse.getStatus();
                }
                Log.i("Update", "password call" + apiResponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return newPassword;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what I'm doing to execute it:

```
String oldPassword = changePassOld.getText().toString();
String newPassword = changePassNew.getText().toString();
AsyncTask task = new UpdatePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, ProfileFragment.this.getContext());
task.execute();
```

Edit: I have noticed that i only have `doInBackground` but even when i had `preExecute`, it still wouldn't work

Comment: have you debugged your  `postExecute()` method? are you sure that there is no return from `doInBackground`

Comment: Yeah i have and returns nothing

Comment: Then your problem is definitely in your  `doInBackground` body, it could return null, debug it and see where the problem is!

Comment: I've tried but that's what i don't understand, nothing comes up, so it doesn't even seem to be reaching doInBackground, which makes me wonder if I've missed something

Comment: I don't see anything strange or I myself don't do with `AsyncTask`  except the `static` way of implementation! I hope someone figures out what the problem is

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help anyway. It'll no doubt be a really simple fixed which will all become clear once i'ts done lol

Comment: `apiResponse.getStatus()`... Why are you returning this? That is not your new password. Anyways, your AsyncTask looks fine. Please show the code where you actually expect the value of `doInBackground` or `onPostExecute` to return to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AsyncTask doesn't always call but when it does, it comes up null?

It is the most interesting AsyncTask ;)

---

Generally speaking, you seem to not be returning the data to the point where you expect it (or a `return null` condition is being hit).

You can instead define a callback.

```
public interface PasswordChangeListener {
    void onPasswordChanged(String oldPass, String newPass);
}
```

Implement that on your Fragment class

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment 
    implements PasswordChangeListener { // See here

    ...

    @Override
    public void onPasswordChanged(String oldPass, String newPass) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
            String.format("Changed %s to %s", oldPass, newPass), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Call your AsyncTask after you add that callback as a parameter

(Context usually goes first, by the way)

```
new UpdatePassword(
    ProfileFragment.this.getActivity(), 
    oldPassword, newPassword, 
    ProfileFragment.this).execute();
```

**Suggestion**: You should `return apiResponse;` from `doInBackground`

And implement `onPostExecute` on the AsyncTask with that suggestion in mind

```
@Override 
public void onPostExecute(ApiResponse result) {
    if (apiResponse != null && apiResponse.isSuccess()) {
        if (this.callback != null) {
            callback.onPasswordChanged(this.oldPassword, this.newPassword);
        } else {
            Log.w("Password change", "Password callback not set!");
        }
    } else {
        // TODO: Error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a null reference on this line:    'HttpRequestUtils httpRequestUtils = new HttpRequestUtils(context);'

Comment: All im getting now is `E/Editor: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()`

Comment: 1) That httpRequestUtils line should not error if the `context` isn't null... 2) That error is unrelated to your AsyncTask